Predictive Models for Imbalanced Data
I have data with labels $y_i \in \{0,1\}$ and some features $x_i$. Most $y$'s are 0 (e.g. 99% to 1%). I want to fit a random forest classification model on this data.
I was wondering if this approach is used in statistics to avoid problems with imbalances in the data (e.g. a combination of bagging and resampling):

Get all rows where $y_i = 1$ (let's call this set $B$)
Randomly sample from the $y_i = 0$ rows to get a set the same size as $B$ (call each sample $S_k$)
Train a model $f_k$ on $B \cup S_k$
Do this $K$ times to get models $f_1, f_2, ..., f_K$

Then for any new input $x_{new}$, our prediction is just the average:
$$ \text{prediction} = \frac{f_1(x_{new}) + f_2(x_{new}) + ... + f_K(x_{new})}{K} $$
Then : For any new observation $x_{new}$, if we have $K$ models, we can define the agreement score $A(x_{new})$ as:
$$ A(x_{new}) = \max\left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^K I(f_k(x_{new}) = 0)}{K}, \frac{\sum_{k=1}^K I(f_k(x_{new}) = 1)}{K}\right) $$
This gives us a score between 0.5 (perfect disagreement) and 1.0 (perfect agreement). A threshold can be chosen that decides what level of Agreement should be accepted as a threshold (e.g. see if higher model agreement correlates to more accurate predictions)?

That's a great idea.
I recommend you to see this post(https://www.kaggle.com/code/janiobachmann/credit-fraud-dealing-with-imbalanced-datasets). I think it can help you deal with imbalance data.
